# FFT with fewer outputs than inputs

Tags: fft

Is it possible to write a FFT function, where there is fewer outputs than inputs? What in mean is, we would start computing 16-point FFT, and our result would end up be 12-point.

If it is possible than do we loose any data in the procoess of reduction?

Comment: If your input data is real and you compute a 2N-point FFT, you only need N + 1 points, as the last N-1 points correspond to the negative frequencies and have no "new" information.

Answer (score 3):

The FFT is just an implementation of the DFT, which is an invertible operation on any vector composed of complex numbers.

Since invertible operations need to be surjective:

No, an FFT can't have less outputs than inputs.

You are, probably, looking for something that "condenses" your data, e.g. looking for features, or projecting onto a smaller vector space that is sufficient to describe your signals of interest; keywords you might be looking for would be "feature extraction" or "compressive sensing".

However, I think it might be sensible for you to post a new question, describing exactly *what* you actually want to do (and not focused on employing the FFT itself).